# Restrict access in apache except for one URL when using "master file" and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-http-server, php, authentication, mod-rewrite

I successfully applied basic authentication to my entire website but now I want to make an exception for a specific URL pattern.  From what I understand, I can use the  directive but so far, it isn't working.

Perhaps what complicates matters is that every page of my site is actually /master.php and the only different from page to page is the query string, which instructs master.php to inject the page-specific content.  This gives me a really simple skin solution.  Together with mod_rewrite, I have friendly URLs like this:

```
mysite.com/stats
mysite.com/about
```

which get rewritten to:

```
mysite.com/master.php?p=stats
mysite.com/master.php?p=about
```

In this setup, is it possible to require authentication for the entire site except for /about, for instance?  Note that /about may have a query string after it, which is why I need to make an exception for a URL *pattern*, not just a specific URL.

If it makes any difference, here are some specifics:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Apache 2.4.10
- My rewrites are in the site.conf file, not
  in .htaccess files.

Comment: Check this topic and adjust it on your URIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731109/getting-authentication-required-when-requesting-instead-of-index-php?rq=1

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!  How should I accept this as the answer?  Also, is it poor form to answer with a link instead of the actual answer, since the content on the linked page could change or go away, or is that only for non StackExchange content?

Comment: You posted on Superuser and my link is from stackoverflow so i couldn't mark as duplicate, you can either answer your own question or i can do it, if you didn't change anything from the other topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mod_setenvif`:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/about$" allow=yes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /var/www/webinterface/.htpasswd
Options +FollowSymLinks
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from All
Require valid-user
Allow from env=allow
```

→ bottom part blocks entire content except if you are logged in or if `allow=yes`, which is only set if the request uri is the about site.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731109/getting-authentication-required-when-requesting-instead-of-index-php?rq=1

Comment: I'll copy over my comment/question from StackOverflow too: Do you not have to put the block that begins with AuthType into a <Directory>, <Location> or <Files> etc. directive?

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: Hard to explain in a comment.  When I copy and pasted the above lines into my .conf file and restarted Apache, it complained with an AH00526 error: "AuthType not allowed here".  (Note that I got the error only after executing: systemctl status apache2.service.)  That's when I put everything starting with AuthType and ending with Allow from env=allow in between <Directory /var/www/mysite></Directory>.  Once I did that and restarted, it worked.